# ruby symbol in the ruby class attr_accessor

Tags: ruby

Example

```
 class Persion
    attr_accessor :name, :age
 end
```

Can I write in this format?

```
 class Persion
    attr_accessor name, age
 end
```

Comment: I have try it,there is a error ,undefined method `name=' for #<Foo:0x9410268> (NoMethodError),I think I have know it now!

Comment: What makes it tricky is that you cannot do this wit `attr_` methods, but you can do it with `alias`.

Comment: @sawa good point, you have to keep in mind that `alias` is a *keyword* and `attr_accessor` is a *method*

Answer (score 1):

No, because the ones in the first example are symbols, while in the second example it will try to call nonexistent `name` and `age` methods, which will result in an exception.

Comment: What makes it tricky is that you cannot do this wit `attr_` methods, but you can do it with `alias`.

Comment: To elaborate on sawa's point, the difference between `alias` and `attr_accessor` is that `alias` is a keyword (so it can evaluate things specially) while `attr_accessor` is just a normal method that has to obey the same evaluation rules as any other.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course you can. `Module#attr_accessor` is a method just like any other method, there is nothing special about how you pass arguments to it. You don't *have* to pass in a `Symbol` literal, you can pass in any expression that evaluates to a `Symbol`:

```
class Persion
  class << self
    private
    def name; :name end
    def age; :age end
  end

  attr_accessor name, age
end

Persion.new.tap do |p| p.name = 'Foo'; p.age = 42 end
# => #<Persion:0x007f7f70fc5160 @age=42, @name="Foo">
```

Answer (score 0):

No, You cant do that, because in the implementation of `attr_accessor`, it applies `rb_to_id` function on the passed arguments which expects a symbol and returns it's `id`.

You can find the source code of `attr_accessor` [here](http://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_2_180/Module/attr_accessor).